# 400 Bad request exception when send JSON string to server from client

Tags: c#, json, rest

Actually sending json string(Post) to server got 400 bad request exception,

below Url i got this exception

> _http://---.---.--.---:---/SignUp/SignupUser/{JSON STRING}/{PASSWORD}

so the JSON string and password is given below

> _http://---.---.--.---:----/SignUp/SignupUser/{"SessionId":"99c77c9b-043e-4611-a011-e774c614e887","PassWord":"234434343434","UserName":"john_mcclane","FirstName":"John","LastName":"mcclane","NickName":"Bruno","Gender":0,"DateTime":"2013-12-19T10:39:37","AddressLine1":"Paradigm Talent Agency NY","AddressLine2":"360 Park Ave South, 16th Floor","City":"New York","State":"New York","Country":"USA","Zip":"N.Y. 10010","EmailId":"Bruno_diehard@email.com","MobileNumber":"7189615565","AlternativeNumber":"9179615565","ProofType":"License","ProofNumber":"I1234562","IsDogAllowed":true,"IsDrinkersAllowed":true,"IsSmokersAllowed":true}/{234434343434}

please tell what i did wrong in it.

Note : I am trying this in the advance rest client google chrome.

Comment: Are you sending it through POST? why don't you send the data in the request body rather than in the uri?

Comment: Try url-encoding it, if it has to be a GET request.

Comment: @Hariprasad : I am new for rest service, Please provide me how to do with request body

Comment: @towr : I changed Content-Type to url-encoding , again same exception

Comment: And I tried some GET request it will work, like simple string values, when i giving Json string having problem.

Comment: Have you looked at your server logs? Perhaps it gives a reason why it's a bad request.

Comment: @towr : Great point, I will check that.

Comment: @VikramBose: Even if you succeed to send Json data through GET, it's outright wrong to send user name and password like that. See this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238728/security-is-it-ok-to-send-a-username-and-password-via-http-get). Which client platform are you using? HTML/Javascript/C++/C#/Java?

Comment: @Hariprasad : I am using Advanced rest client tool to access this, Andriod and IOS developer will access this, Actually here the password appending is possible in POST method for outside from different clients?

Comment: You can find an image [here](http://imgur.com/sSbh61L) which shows how to send the POST request using Advacned http client. But, a lot of questions still remain. Does your server code support a POST request like this? Or does it require the client to send request through GET?If latter is the case, I would recommend to change it and use POST method instead because that will solve a lot of security loop holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the POST request with two arguments (JSON object and password). The typical REST service post request can have only one argument. So, try with one argument by sending the password with the JSON object itself.

Comment: Yes If i add password in the json object, Its works perfectly, Thanks Petchirajan